# Demo of web site that is vulnerable to command injection

Tags: web-application, attacks, professional-education

I'm looking for a demonstration web site that shows an example of a web site that is vulnerable to command injection: where I can inject something and get the web site to run a shell command.  (This is solely for demonstration purposes, to help teach others about the dangers of command injection.)  Does anyone know of any demonstration web site like this?

If the location of the command injection vulnerability is not documented publicly, please describe where the command injection vulnerability is (e.g., the page and parameter that is vulnerable).  I'm not looking for a puzzle to learn how to perform command injection attacks; I'm already familiar with it.  Instead, I'm looking for an example that I can use to show the problem to others.

Comment: Download webgoat... stay off the network when running the webgoat on your machine.. There is dedicated lesson on command injection under injection attacks. Use the hints if you don't want to spend time on figuring out how to solve the lesson

Answer (score 4):

The [WebGoat Project](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/OWASP_WebGoat_Project) has a lesson specifically on command injection ;)

Answer (score 1):

Try [Hack This Site](http://www.hackthissite.org/).  It has examples, in the form of "puzzles," of a number of vulnerabilities.

Comment: Can you tell me which "missions" on Hack This Site demonstrates a shell command injection vulnerability?  There are a lot of missions there.  (Also, are there any "missions" that demonstrate this flaw with a realistic-looking site?)

Comment: Update: basic7 seems to be an example of shell command injection, though the web site provides only super-limited emulation of the behavior of a vulnerable app and is a non-realistic example.  realistic11 has a command injection and is a realistic-looking website, but it provides super-limited emulation of the command injection vulnerability which prevents exploiting it in the most natural ways (e.g., providing any command to run on the server other than `ls`).

Answer (score 0):

this vulnerable web application will help you understand OWASP top 10 and you can find  command injection vulnerable pages in it , try them and here is the link
[mutillidae](http://www.irongeek.com/i.php?page=security/mutillidae-deliberately-vulnerable-php-owasp-top-10)

Answer (score 0):

Download iso file from links below. There are good exercises.

Web For Pentester : 
https://www.pentesterlab.com/exercises/web_for_pentester

Web For Pentester II : 
https://pentesterlab.com/exercises/web_for_pentester_II